# Glass Mapper failed to map to property 'Description' on type '...'

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I think I might be facing a major bug with Glass Mapper at the moment. When loading a page, it sometimes crashes when trying to map a model.

I can reproduce this bug and I have a very good idea about the cause. It happens for example when I modify one specific version (language), but keep it in draft (workflow). When I publish the item, it seems like the cache used by Glass Mapper contains the shared data only.

I'm using Glass Mapper 3.5 at the moment and I'm not very comfortable with updating to version 4 knowing that it implies the important changes.

Anyone have any idea about a way to solve this?

Thanks

```
Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException
Message: Failed to map to property 'Description' on type 'CPA.Data.SitecoreEntity.Pages.ContentPage'
Source: Glass.Mapper
   at Glass.Mapper.AbstractDataMapper.MapCmsToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext)
   at Glass.Mapper.Configuration.AbstractTypeConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClassb.<CreatePropertyExpression>b__a(Object obj, AbstractDataMappingContext context)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source: System.Core
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.SetCapacity(Int32 newSize, Boolean forceNewHashCodes)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value)
   at Sitecore.Caching.ItemPathsCache.<>c__DisplayClass10.<AddToKeyIndex>b__e(String key, HashSet`1 oldValue)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, TValue addValue, Func`3 updateValueFactory)
   at Sitecore.Caching.ItemPathsCache.AddToKeyIndex(ItemPathCacheKey partialCacheKey, String longId)
   at Sitecore.Caching.ItemPathsCache.AddMapping(Item item, ItemPathType itemPathType, String path)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String separator, ItemPathType type, Item root, Int32 level)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String separator, ItemPathType type)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.DoGetPath(Item currentItem, String from, String separator, ItemPathType type)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.GetPath(Item currentItem, String from, String separator, ItemPathType type)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemPath.get_LongID()
   at Sitecore.Caching.AccessResultCache.AddRecord(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType, AccessResult accessResult)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAncestorAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationProvider.GetAccess(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(ISecurable entity, AccessRight right, Account account)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetItemUnderTestProcessor.Process(GetItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Links.MediaLinkExpander.Expand(String& text, UrlOptions urlOptions)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.LinkParser.ExpandDynamicLinks(String text, UrlOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks(String text, Boolean resolveSites)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.ExpandLinks.Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreFieldStringMapper.GetField(Field field, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
   at Glass.Mapper.AbstractDataMapper.MapCmsToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext)
```

Comment: this could have something to do with the enforceVersionPresence setting I think.

Comment: I don't think that this setting is built-in in Sitecore. Is this what you are referring to? http://www.sitecore.net/sv-se/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/elizabeth-spranzani/posts/2014/03/fallback-series-post-3.aspx. If that's the case, I can't see why I need to install some community module to work around this bug in Glass Mapper.

Comment: http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/VersionCountDisabler I think he was referring to this. Did you manage to resolve this @MaximeDaigneault be great if you could share your answer :).

Comment: Yes, after further investigation, I found out that it had absolutely nothing to do with GlassMapper. I was able to reproduce the same bug without GlassMapper. The problem is with the ItemPath cache. For unknown reason, the ItemPath cache will currupt itself.